Pyarrow error with ray & lightning on databricks
I am trying to train a neural net with pytorch lightning on ray on a databricks cluster. As a start, I copied the example from https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/train/getting-started-pytorch-lightning.html. Unfortunately, the training stops after one epoch with a RayTaskError.
Is anything wrong with the logging location? Might it be a ray bug? Or compability problems between python, ray and lightning? I am a little lost here as I don't understand the error message. Has anyone of you encountered anything similar?
I set up the ray cluster as follows:
from ray.util.spark import setup_ray_cluster, shutdown_ray_cluster
eps = 1
ray_worker_memory = 410
remote_conn_str = setup_ray_cluster(
  max_worker_nodes=8,
  min_worker_nodes=1,
  memory_worker_node=ray_worker_memory*0.7*10**9-eps,
  object_store_memory_worker_node=ray_worker_memory*0.3*10**9-eps,
  collect_log_to_path="/dbfs/test/ray_collected_logs"
)

I took the code from the tutorial mentioned above:
import os
import tempfile

import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.models import resnet18
from torchvision.datasets import FashionMNIST
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor, Normalize, Compose
import lightning.pytorch as pl

import ray.train.lightning
from ray.train.torch import TorchTrainer

# Model, Loss, Optimizer
class ImageClassifier(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ImageClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.model = resnet18(num_classes=10)
        self.model.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(
            1, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False
        )
        self.criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, y = batch
        outputs = self.forward(x)
        loss = self.criterion(outputs, y)
        self.log("loss", loss, on_step=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        return torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=0.001)


def train_func():
    # Data
    transform = Compose([ToTensor(), Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))])
    data_dir = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "data")
    train_data = FashionMNIST(root=data_dir, train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=128, shuffle=True)

    # Training
    model = ImageClassifier()
    # [1] Configure PyTorch Lightning Trainer.
    trainer = pl.Trainer(
        max_epochs=10,
        devices="auto",
        accelerator="auto",
        strategy=ray.train.lightning.RayDDPStrategy(),
        plugins=[ray.train.lightning.RayLightningEnvironment()],
        callbacks=[ray.train.lightning.RayTrainReportCallback()],
        # [1a] Optionally, disable the default checkpointing behavior
        # in favor of the `RayTrainReportCallback` above.
        enable_checkpointing=False,
    )
    trainer = ray.train.lightning.prepare_trainer(trainer)
    trainer.fit(model, train_dataloaders=train_dataloader)

# [2] Configure scaling and resource requirements.
scaling_config = ray.train.ScalingConfig(num_workers=2, use_gpu=False)

# [3] Launch distributed training job.
trainer = TorchTrainer(
    train_func,
    scaling_config=scaling_config,
    run_config=ray.train.RunConfig(
        storage_path="/dbfs/test/ray_collected_logs", 
        name="lightning", 
        ),
)
result: ray.train.Result = trainer.fit()

# [4] Load the trained model.
with result.checkpoint.as_directory() as checkpoint_dir:
    model = ImageClassifier.load_from_checkpoint(
        os.path.join(
            checkpoint_dir,
            ray.train.lightning.RayTrainReportCallback.CHECKPOINT_NAME,
        ),
    )

After one epoch, I got the error:
RayTaskError(OSError): ray::_Inner.train() (pid=8556, ip=10.139.64.13, actor_id=84c7d46bc785ca0be4760e0d02000000, repr=TorchTrainer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/tune/trainable/trainable.py", line 331, in train
    raise skipped from exception_cause(skipped)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/train/_internal/utils.py", line 53, in check_for_failure
    ray.get(object_ref)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ray.exceptions.RayTaskError(OSError): ray::_RayTrainWorker__execute.get_next() (pid=8728, ip=10.139.64.13, actor_id=cb307feab981f85ea2fea9bd02000000, repr=<ray.train._internal.worker_group.RayTrainWorker object at 0x7f63f35fb890>)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/train/_internal/worker_group.py", line 33, in __execute
    raise skipped from exception_cause(skipped)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/train/_internal/utils.py", line 169, in discard_return_wrapper
    train_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.ipykernel/3049/command-3520572809263628-1931200599", line 60, in train_func
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/trainer.py", line 543, in fit
    call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/call.py", line 43, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
    return trainer.strategy.launcher.launch(trainer_fn, *args, trainer=trainer, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/strategies/launchers/subprocess_script.py", line 105, in launch
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/trainer.py", line 579, in _fit_impl
    self._run(model, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/trainer.py", line 986, in _run
    results = self._run_stage()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/trainer.py", line 1030, in _run_stage
    self.fit_loop.run()
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/loops/fit_loop.py", line 206, in run
    self.on_advance_end()
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/loops/fit_loop.py", line 376, in on_advance_end
    call._call_callback_hooks(trainer, "on_train_epoch_end", monitoring_callbacks=False)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/lightning/pytorch/trainer/call.py", line 210, in _call_callback_hooks
    fn(trainer, trainer.lightning_module, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/train/lightning/_lightning_utils.py", line 289, in on_train_epoch_end
    train.report(metrics=metrics, checkpoint=checkpoint)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/train/_internal/session.py", line 657, in wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/train/_internal/session.py", line 748, in report
    _get_session().report(metrics, checkpoint=checkpoint)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/train/_internal/session.py", line 426, in report
    persisted_checkpoint = self.storage.persist_current_checkpoint(checkpoint)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/train/_internal/storage.py", line 542, in persist_current_checkpoint
    _pyarrow_fs_copy_files(
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-94c29ff9-2f5f-4216-b6c2-096d629bb4ad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/train/_internal/storage.py", line 110, in _pyarrow_fs_copy_files
    return pyarrow.fs.copy_files(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyarrow/fs.py", line 269, in copy_files
    _copy_files_selector(source_fs, source_sel,
  File "pyarrow/_fs.pyx", line 1627, in pyarrow._fs._copy_files_selector
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 91, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
OSError: [Errno 22] Error writing bytes to file. Detail: [errno 22] Invalid argument

The package versions (of the probably crucial packages) are:
pytorch-lightning              2.3.3
ray                            2.32.0
I am running the code on a databricks cluster with Databricks Runtime Version 15.2 ML (includes Apache Spark 3.5.0, Scala 2.12). The python version in this DBR is 3.11.0rc1.
Using an older DBR (14.3 ML) which comes with python 3.10.12 leads to the same error.
To check whether the path is a valid directory, I executed this:
dbutils.fs.mkdirs("/dbfs/test/ray_collected_logs/test_dir")
dbutils.fs.put("/dbfs/test/ray_collected_logs/test_file.txt", "This is a test.")

and the test worked. The problem above remains unsolved.
